# How to import the QML-Book examples into QT Creator 3.4.0?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

How can I import [these code examples](https://github.com/qmlbook/qmlbook/tree/master/en/ch04/src/concepts) into QT Creator 3.4.0 ? I tried the available import options but they don't work.

I tried to create an empty QML project and add the `rectangle.qml` file to it. When I tried to run it, nothing showed up.

The book examples contain files .qmlproject - which seems to be a project descriptor. I wonder if it is somehow possible to import these .qmlproject files into QT Creator, click and run the examples.

I think this link might help in finding the solution : https://forum.qt.io/topic/27525/what-is-qmlproject-file/3 .

[image]

Comment: You have to be more explicit than "they don't work". What were the exact steps that you tried (names of menus, etc.)? Also, was there an error message? Did it crash? Did your computer explode?

Comment: :) I am making a screencast, that is the easiest way to explain the situation.

Comment: Here should be available the screencast when it finished uploading : http://youtu.be/XGpWSQCLWXk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I'd say that you should go to `File > Open File or Project...` and select the `.qmlproject` and you're done, but support for this type of project file [was disabled by default](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/101847/). If you try to do this now (I believe the change is in Creator 3.4), you'll just get an error message about Creator not supporting the mime type of the file, or something. Unfortunately, this is not a very useful error message for a beginner, and it won't tell you how to fix the problem.

If you want to use `.qmlproject` files in newer versions of Creator, you have to navigate to `Help > About Plugins...` and enable the `QmlProjectManager` plugin (it's under the `Qt Quick` section) by checking the box.

So this is how you should normally open project files in Qt Creator. As for the window not showing up, that's also commonly encountered and can be fixed by [making the root item in your scene a Window](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine.html#details):

> Unlike QQuickView, QQmlApplicationEngine does not automatically create a root window. If you are using visual items from Qt Quick, you will need to place them inside of a Window.

Qt Creator's new project wizard handles this for you when you create a new Qt Quick project, as you saw when you got the "Hello World" window to open in your video. It was when you loaded `concepts/rectangle.qml` which had a `Rectangle` as its root item, that it stopped showing up. That QML file was likely used in a project where a `QQuickView` was displaying it.